# Unexpected behaviour of max_bucket_count function

Tags: c++, c++11

According to cplusplus.com, unordered_set::max_bucket_count() function should return the maximum number of buckets the container can have on the system running the program http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/max_bucket_count/

However, with visual studio 2015, the output of bucket_count and max_bucket_count is same, even when number of elements in unordered_set is small.

```
unordered_set<string> us;
ifstream ifs("small_words.txt");
string word;
while (ifs >> word) {
    us.insert(word);
}

cout << "Number of elements: " << us.size() << endl;
cout << "bucket_count: " << us.bucket_count() << endl;
cout << "max_bucket_count: " << us.max_bucket_count() << endl;
```

Output:

```
Number of elements: 41
bucket_count: 64
max_bucket_count: 64
```

Is there a valid explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Here is an easy one: VS is not standards compliant?  :)

Comment: This makes the method max_bucket_count() essentially useless. Is this behaviour documented somewhere?

Comment: I made no claim that it wasn't standard compliant in a useful way.

Comment: @Yakk `max_bucket_count` is as useful as `max_size` :P

Comment: I'm curious what the use case for `max_bucket_count()` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in VS 2015 Update 1:

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1764567

Example output:

```
Number of elements: 41
bucket_count: 64
max_bucket_count: 536870911
```